# Object references and copying

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I still can't understand the concept of how objects are copied as reference.

A variable assigned to an object stores not the object itself, but its “address in memory” – in other words, “a reference” to it.

Can someone please explain it in simpler way with example ?

Comment: Include a programing language tag...

Comment: Thanks, added JavaScript, anyway isn't the concept the same in all programming languages ?

Comment: No, because memory handling model is various across programing language...

Comment: In JavaScript, Every object are copied as reference. Because Object is expensive... So what is your question about ?

Comment: What I understood so far, is that when you assign an object to another variable, that variable has the original copy of JavaScript and if we change anything in that variable we are automatically changing the original object.

Comment: if it refer to that object, then Yes!